# Why Youtube mobile app doesn't play video in background?

Tags: mobile-application, experience

One of the reasons I could think of ads and viewing video is what makes them money, they want you to see ads but don't we also use youtube to listen to music and other audio-only contents? People will listen to ads as well. What do you guys think?

Comment: The only way you're likely to find a conclusive answer to this is by contacting YouTube and asking them directly - The only thing you'll get here is guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Google offers this exact thing in a paid service called YouTube Red. The only reason why it's not in the free app is to let Google and the content creators it licenses from make more money.